# Pycharm Not Displaying Line on Plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a graph from a for-loop from z=0 to z=3.8 in 0.001 increments. I then have the program solve for X_e and I would like to plot z on the y-axis and X_e on the x-axis. However, when I run the code, the program provides all the values for z and X_e and shows a plot but no line is created. Below is my code and below that is the plot it creates but doesn't finish.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

case=int(input('Which Case [1 (PWR) or 2 (BWR)]? '))

if case == 1: # PWR
    H = 3.80 # m
    Lc = 3.80 # m
    D_rod = 0.0095 # m
    pitch = 0.0125 # m

    G = 3460 # kg/m^2-s
    q_0 = 33000 # W/m - Linear heat rate
    P_0 = 15 # MPa - Initial pressure
    T_f_in = 551 # Kelvin - Inlet temperature
    T_sat = 373 # Kelvin
    cp = 4.22 # kJ/kg
    hfg = 2256.4 # kJ/kg

    heated_parameter = 3.14 * D_rod # m
    area = pitch**2 - 0.25 * 3.14 * D_rod**2 # m^2
    volume = 0.5 * 3.14 * (D_rod)**2 * H # m^3

    circumference = 2*3.14*(D_rod/2) # m

    for z in np.arange(0,3.8,0.001):
        print(z)

        X_e = - q_0 * heated_parameter / (G * circumference * area * hfg) * H/3.14 * math.cos(3.14 *   z/H) - cp * (T_sat - T_f_in)/hfg

        print(X_e)
        plt.plot(X_e,z)

    plt.show()
```

This is the graph that is created.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBg1M.png]

Comment: Also, you can use vectorization and get rid of the for loop. Otherwise it will take ages to execute.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing single points to `plt.plot`. Use `np.cos` (which is vectorized) and skip the loop:

```
z = np.arange(0, 3.8, 0.001)
X_e = -q_0 * heated_parameter / (G * circumference * area * hfg) * H/3.14 * np.cos(3.14 * z/H) - cp * (T_sat - T_f_in)/hfg

plt.plot(X_e, z)
```

Output:

[image]

You might also consider using `np.pi` instead of `3.14`.